# flutter: convert Text widget to JSON

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I convert a Text widget (and other Widgets) to JSON?

I'm trying to save an object to SharedPreferences, but incredibly I can't seem to find any information on this. I'm hoping there's something I can do like I did with the DateTime to make it JSON-convertible.

My Activity class:

```
class Activity {
  String state;
  bool visible;
  DateTime visibleAfter;
  bool firstView;
  Widget menuText;
  Widget route;

  Activity(this.state, this.visible, this.visibleAfter, this.firstView, this.menuText, this.route);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'state': state,
        'visible': visible,
        'visibleAfter': visibleAfter.toIso8601String(),
        'firstView': firstView,
        'menuText': menuText,
        'route': route,
      };

  factory Activity.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new Activity(
        json['state'], json['visible'], DateTime.parse(json['visibleAfter']), json['firstView'], json['menuText'], json['route']);
  }
}
```

If I try and write it, I get an error (Note: writing works fine without the Widget in the object)

```
json.encode(
    activityStates.map((k, v) => MapEntry(k, v.toJson())),
    /////// Unhandled Exception: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'Text'
));

/*   These include routes that I would like to map to, like WelcomeScreen
var defaultActivityStates = {
  'Welcome': Activity('review', true, DateTime.now(), false, Text('welcome'), WelcomeScreen),
  'SingleDigitEdit': Activity('todo', true, DateTime.now(), false, Text('test'), SingleDigitEditScreen),
  'SingleDigitPractice': Activity('todo', true, DateTime.now(), false, Text('test'), SingleDigitPractice), 
}
*/
```

Comment: fi a state is a string, and you are trying to map activityStates, which is presumably a list of strings, you cant say: v.toJson() because string doesnt have a method called JSON.  More importantly, I dont see your values.  Can you post sample data you used?

Comment: sorry it's a little unclear, i'll update it

Answer (score 0):

Your `menuText` is a Widget (which is an instance of a class).  You can't serialize that to JSON, as JSON only supports simple types.  Instead, serialize the string content.

```
class Activity {
  String state;
  bool visible;
  DateTime visibleAfter;
  bool firstView;
  String menuText; // change to String
```

When `menuText` is a String and not a Widget, it will serialize to JSON.  Everywhere you want to use it as a widget, just use `Text(menuText)`

Comment: That's really unfortunate, because I have other more complex Widgets that I would like to include in Activity's parameters as well, like an entire custom route...

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way around it.  You'll have to find a way to serialize the Widgets to/from the types that JSON supports (strings, numbers, boolean, arrays, JavaScript-like objects).  It can't represent class instances like Widgets.

Comment: @MattTakao All things you want to serialize, need to also be Serializable.  So You may not be able to serialize a widget, but you could extend widget and have a to/from Json which you can then store pertenant information such as states or data etc.  Then it would work